# Hosting ASP.NET Core to IIS returns Internal Server error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

Deployed ASP.NET MVC `Core 1.1.1` on `Windows 2012 Server R2`. Followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore1x) ASP.NET article (installed DotNetCore.1.0.5_1.1.2-WindowsHosting bundle etc). App runs fine as localhost on the server if we follow the following steps:

1. In cmd from root dir of the app, ran: dotnet MyWebapplication.dll
2. Noticed that application is running and waiting for responses on localhost:5000.
3. Opened the browser on the host server and navigated to: `http://localhost:5000`
4. Home page opened as expected
   But when we navigate to the `http://IP Address/MyWebapplication` on a different desktop on the same network, we get the `500 - Internal Server Error`

**NOTE**: We tested that if we host a simple web app (**not** ASP.NET Core) with just one Index.html page on IIS, we can access the app from another machine on the same network via, say, `http://IP Address/MySimpleHtmlApp`. So issue seems to be related to something on ASP.NET Core deployment on IIS. **Question**: What we may be missing and how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**:
The IIS has default port 80 that is open. When we run the app directly from IIS on the server (i.e., http://localhost:80/MyWebapplication) it gives the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\D:\TestApp\PublishOutput\web.config

Requested URL      http://localhost:80/TestWebApp

Physical Path      D:\TestApp\PublishOutput
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined
Config Source:
   -1: 
    0:
```

Following is the **web.config** file (created by `VS2017`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\TestWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 21c38c6d-7aff-4624-b310-a0f5f766b461-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, you're not really deploying this to IIS; you're self-hosting. If you want to run it under IIS, you need to create a site in IIS for it, drop in the published code, and configure the App Pool to run "No Managed Code". Then, you can pull up the site under whatever bindings you've added for it in IIS.

Second, your test case of a "simple website", it not utilizing a non-standard web port (it's using 80), while your ASP.NET Core app is (5000). This may very well be due to a firewall you have running, as most firewall appliances will block access by default to any non-standard port. You'll either need to open up a rule for that port on your firewall or host it on port 80, like you're doing with your "simple website".

Comment: We've done everything mentioned in first paragraph of your response. Under Default Web Site of IIS we just created an Application with an App Pool to be "No Managed Code" - and pointed the app to the published folder. To address second paragraph of your response, I've added and **UPDATE** section to my post.

Comment: I got it resolved. The issue was that although I had installed DotNetCore.1.0.5_1.1.2-WindowsHosting bundle but the ASPNETCore was not showing up in `IIS->Modules`. So, I uninstalled the bundle and the restarted the machine, installed the bundle again, restarted the machine (as precaution). I do want to thank you for the second paragraph of your response as it provided me more insight into port elated issues (non-standard port vs standard port, firewall blockage etc.).

Comment: Yeah, you have to restart the machine entirely after installing the hosting bundle. Resetting IIS is not enough.

Comment: Agreed. Item 2 of the `Install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle` section of this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x) reads: Restart the system or execute net stop was /y followed by net start w3svc from a command prompt to pick up a change to the system PATH.